# Gradle dependency problem in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, coil

Can't Sync Gradle, when trying to make Coil implementation.

```
dependencies {

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation"io.coil-kt:coil:1.3.0"}
```

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:1.4.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Comment: From which repository are you trying to get the dependencies? Can you share your repositories block from build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are writing like this?

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.3.0")
```

since i am able to sync with `material-1.4.1` and `coil:1.3.0` versions